# How to create live stream playback client in Native React?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to create a simple mobile app that receives live stream feed from a server and displays it for both Android and iOs. I searched on internet, but I only found how to send the feed, not how to display it.

Currently I have the feed displayed on a website trough an `<iframe>`

`<iframe width = '100%' height = '1150' src = 'https://adm.infoo.tv/vodplayer?channel=14&playlist=126&autoplay=1&raport=0.56&bgcolor=BFBFBF&itembgcolor=FFFFFF&hovercolor=CF102D&videoperpage=8&notdisplayplaylists=0' style = ...></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

Usually streams services have their own API or libs you can use with ReactNative to configure your player, if that's not the case for the stream service you are using you may try to use the `iframe` inside a `WebView` component on your app.

It's not the best solution, also if this iframe renders any kind of flashplayer it will not work as expecte as well.

My suggestion is for you to get information on which stream provider your backend uses so you can ask for a ReactNative plugin or a native API (in this case you will need to build the bridge)

Wish success on your project.